# Loop through rows of df and perform calculations based on if-statement

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to calculate my brokerage fees in several currencies into USD. So if I paid the fee in EUR, the fee should be multiplied with that days EUR/USD exchange rate.

Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Fee Coin": ["EUR", "BTC"],
                   "Fee": [3, 0.0005],
                    "USD Price": [1.05, 1.1],
                     "BTC Price": [24000, 27000]})
```

The output for the first row should be *3.15* and the second should be *13.5*. The output should be displayed in a new column which I have tried calling **Fee in USD**.

What I have tried, which gives the wrong calculations:

```
for value in df["Fee Coin"]:
    if value == "EUR":
        df["Fee in USD"] = df.Fee*df["USD Price"]
    elif value == "BTC":
        df["Fee in USD"] = df.Fee*df["BTC Price"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only two categories: EUR and BTC, you can use np.where.

```
df["Fee in USD"] = np.where(df["Fee Coin"] == "EUR", df.Fee * df["USD Price"], 
                             df.Fee * df["BTC Price"])
```

Output:

```
   Fee Coin     Fee  USD Price  BTC Price  Fee in USD
0      EUR  3.0000       1.05      24000        3.15
1      BTC  0.0005       1.10      27000       13.50
```

UPDATE:
For multiple currencies it's better to have a map from Fee Coin to column name i.e.

```
currency_to_col = {"EUR": "USD Price", "BTC": "BTC Price", "JPY": "JPY Price"}.
```

Then use np.select

```
condlist = [df["Fee Coin"] == currency for currency in df["Fee Coin"].unique()]
choicelist = [df.Fee * df[currency_to_col[currency]] for currency in df["Fee Coin"].unique()]
df["Fee in USD"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

DataFrame:

```
  Fee Coin     Fee  USD Price  BTC Price  JPY Price
0      EUR  3.0000       1.05      24000       1000
1      BTC  0.0005       1.10      27000       2000
2      JPY  0.2000       1.20      29000       3000
```

Output:

```
  Fee Coin     Fee  USD Price  BTC Price  JPY Price  Fee in USD
0      EUR  3.0000       1.05      24000       1000        3.15
1      BTC  0.0005       1.10      27000       2000       13.50
2      JPY  0.2000       1.20      29000       3000      600.00
```

Comment: This will not work with three or more currencies right?

Comment: No. For that purpose use the @Andrej code.

Comment: Check np.select. If required I can update the answer.

Comment: That one is very neat, Amit. I do have several currencies and np.select solves this very well. For the sake of following my initial df here is how I used it: 
`df["Fee in USD"] = np.select([df["Fee Coin"] == "EUR", df["Fee Coin"] == "BTC"],
                            [df.Fee * df["USD Price"], df.Fee * df["BTC Price"]])`

Comment: I think it will be better to put a map from the currency type to corresponding column name i.e. currency_to_col = {"EUR": "USD Price", "BTC": "BTC Price", "JPY": JPY Price"}. Then we can construct the condlist and choicelist easily.

Comment: Good point. If you make an edit to your post I will mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230668/discussion-between-amit-vikram-singh-and-hobbycoder11).

Answer (score 1):

```
m_eur = df["Fee Coin"] == "EUR"
m_btc = df["Fee Coin"] == "BTC"

df["Fee in USD"] = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[m_eur, "Fee"] * df.loc[m_eur, "USD Price"],
        df.loc[m_btc, "Fee"] * df.loc[m_btc, "BTC Price"],
    ]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Fee Coin     Fee  USD Price  BTC Price  Fee in USD
0      EUR  3.0000       1.05      24000        3.15
1      BTC  0.0005       1.10      27000       13.50
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting wrong calculations is because for every row you're multiplying the entire `df['Fee'] column with df['USD Price'] or df['BTC Price']`. Basically based
on the last row's Fee Coin value your Fee column is getting muliplied by USD/BTC Price column.

In your case since the last row contains "BTC" Coin hence it is getting multiplied by BTC price, resulting in following:

```
   Fee Coin  Fee     USD Price  BTC Price  Fee in USD
0  EUR       3       1.05       24000      72000
1  BTC       0.0005  1.1        27000      13.5
```

So, basically you should multiply particular row value instead of multiplying the entire column

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "Fee Coin"] == "EUR":
        df.loc[i,"Fee in USD"] = df.loc[i,"Fee"]*df.loc[i,"USD Price"]
    elif df.loc[i, "Fee Coin"] == "BTC":
        df.loc[i,"Fee in USD"] = df.loc[i,"Fee"]*df.loc[i,"BTC Price"]
```

Final Dataframe:

```
   Fee Coin  Fee     USD Price  BTC Price  Fee in USD
0  EUR       3       1.05       24000      3.15
1  BTC       0.0005  1.1        27000      13.50
```

**P.S.** For three or more currencies you can add you conditions in the conditional If-Else block.